# Perform an action after interrupting a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads, `threadOne` waits for user input, `threadTwo` interrupts it with an `interrupt()` method before user input is received .
I would like to execute a block of code upon successful interruption of `threadOne`. I tried doing that by catching a `ClosedByInterruptException` within threadOne's `run()` method, but the compiler gives the following error:

`exception ClosedByInterruptException has already been caught`.

Here's the code:

```
class InputInterruption {
public static void main(String[] args) {    

    final Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.print("make a selection: ");
                    String userInput = (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))).readLine();
                    System.out.println(String.format("user input: %s", userInput));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Oops..somethign went wrong.");
                    System.exit(1);
                 } catch(ClosedByInterruptException e) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully interrupted");
                }
        }
    };
    t2.start();



    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("interrupting InputStreamReader");
                t2.interrupt();
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Successfully interrupted");
            }
        }
    };
    t1.start();
}
```

}

Comment: @Gray I thought interrupting a thread with an interrupt() method will throw a ClosedByInterruptException within the thread that is being interrupted (in this case thread t2). Which is why I'm catching it in t2.

Answer (score 1):

ClosedByInterruptionException extends IOException.  Try switching the order of your catch statements.

Comment: it compiles now, but the ClosedByInterruptException is not being caught.

Answer (score 0):

`ClosedByInterruptException` is a subclass of `IOException` so your first catch block intercepts all `IOException` instances including `ClosedByInterruptException`.

Change the order of catch blocks and you are good.

Comment: it compiles now, but the ClosedByInterruptException is not being caught.

Comment: why do you think it is being thrown?

Comment: doesn't interrupting t2 with the interrupt() method throws a ClosedByInterruptException within it? That's what I would expect, but yeah it seems that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for a thread to complete, you could use `Thread.join()`. Change your `t1` code to the following:

```
....
t2.interrupt();
t2.join();
....
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this code myself.

Answer (score 0):

`ClosedByInterruptException` is actually sub class of `IOException`. So even if the try block throws `ClosedByInterruptException` it will be caught by the first catch block with statement:
`catch (IOException e)`. Change the order and you should be good to go.

Comment: it compiles now, but the ClosedByInterruptException is not being caught.

Comment: Well it won't because this exception is thrown blocking an I/O operation upon a *channel*

Comment: I see. So how would I go about executing code upon successful interruption of t2?

Comment: @t2, you are currently interrupting too. But if you just want to do for testing perposes, send the thread to sleep with 3-5s in try block and then call `t2.interrupt();`

Comment: I'm not testing anything, I just want to stop thread t2, execute some code upon successful shutdown of t2 (in this case print out "Successfully interrupted") and then exit the app.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried doing that by catching a ClosedByInterruptException within threadOne's run() method...

Other's have solved the exception compilation error but I do not see any methods that actually throw `ClosedByInterruptException` so I'm surprised your code compiles.  Your code does *not* compile for me in Eclipse for that reason.  Maybe your IDE is not making the unthrown exception an error -- I'd recommend turning on that error/warning.  `ClosedByInterruptException` is only thrown by certain NIO channels that implement `InterruptibleChannel`.

If you are reading from a normal stream, the only way to stop the thread from reading is to close the underlying stream.  In this case you could try to close `System.in` but that may not actually stop the thread from reading unfortunately.  On OS X, closing `System.in` causes the `readLine()` method to return `null` in the reader thread.  You then can continue and execute some sort of code block as necessary.

```
sleep(1000);
System.out.println("closing InputStreamReader");
System.in.close();
```

Then you can do:

```
String userInput =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
if (userInput == null) {
    // stream was closed, do something special
    ...
```

Btw, in the interrupting code you have:

```
try {
    sleep(1000);
    t2.interrupt();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Successfully interrupted");
}
```

The output message there is misleading.  If `sleep(...)` throws a `InterruptedException` then it was the thread that was *sleeping* that was interrupted.  It has nothing to do with the `t2.interrupt()` call.  Just FYI.

Comment: I'm compiling with javac from the command line (no IDE) and am not getting any warnings.
So how would you go about interrupting thread t2 and executing code (in this case printing "Successfully interrupted") upon successful interruption of it?

Comment: You can look for `null` being returned from the `readLine()` method and do something @SB.

Comment: You are right regarding the last bit, `System.out.println("Successfully interrupted");` was placed in the catch (InterruptedException e) by mistake.
Also, after System.in.close(); no code seems to be executing.